# how to convert c# code to perl or openssl cli?

Tags: c#, perl

I have a c# code that convert a string to md5 and then base64 encode it.
I would like to do the same thing with a perl script or linux cli, openssl.
i tried using openssl cli, but i get a different result from the c# code.
can anyone explain and show me how to convert the c# code to linux cli or perl script?

Thanks.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var myString = "7512";
        var o = CalculateMD5Hash(myString);
        Console.WriteLine("Generated String is: {0}", o);

    }

    public static string CalculateMD5Hash(string input) {
        HashAlgorithm ha = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        string prefix = "MD5:";
        string password = "";
        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();
        password = Convert.ToBase64String(ha.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(input)));   
        return prefix+password;
    }
}

# Linux openssl cli
echo -ne '7512' | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | openssl base64
```

When i run the c# code with the string: 7512, i get:
cA5YjDeU2fOJwwnVFPCuAw==

But when i am using the openssl cli command, i get:
FhxcWtUfzIhBV4kFEbPIsA==

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Did you try to use UTF-8 encoding instead of UTF-16 (UnicodeEncoding)?

Comment: @KlausGütter, tried to change the encoding, and the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, got an answer in perlmonks site.
https://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1227872

UnicodeEncoding encodes to UTF-16LE. So in Perl, you'll have to use the Encode module for that, and then either use md5_base64 from Digest::MD5, which removes the padding at the end of the string (==), or, if you want the padding, you'll have to use MIME::Base64 separately:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode qw/encode/;
use Digest::MD5 qw/md5/;
use MIME::Base64 qw/encode_base64/;

my $string = "7512";
my $md5b64 = encode_base64( md5( encode( 'UTF-16LE', $string,
    Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC ) ), "" );
print "Generated String is: MD5:$md5b64\n";

my $expect = "cA5YjDeU2fOJwwnVFPCuAw==";
print $md5b64 eq $expect ? "Matches!\n" : "Doesn't match!\n";

__END__
```